# Docusign iOS SDK integration issue in custom flow(in integrating own backend and docusign iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, swift, docusignapi

We have our own app where we are integrating Doucsign iOS SDK,
What we are doing.
We are uploading PDFs from backend using Docusign API, and then this uploaded PDF needs to be opened in iOS App, using Docusign SDK.
For that we are using iOS SDK call,

```
func displayTemplateForSignature(templateId: String, controller: UIViewController, tabData: Dictionary<String, String>, recipientData: Array<DSMRecipientDefault>, customFields:DSMCustomFields?, onlineSign: Bool, attachmentUrl: URL?, completionHandler: @escaping ((UIViewController?, Error?) -> Void))
```

but we are unable to load the PDF using template id, it also needs recipient data, but we are not adding recipient data while uploading the PDF(template) still it is asking for recipient data in iOS SDK,
If we send some data in recipient data in iOS SDK then it either gives error or dosen't do anything.
The error it gives is

```
2020-08-07 15:30:00.063586+0530 Public Adjuster[8759:2454775] Error encountered during signing: Template has invalid recipient(s) associated with roleName: signer. Current Setup config for DSM_SETUP_RECIPIENT_DEFAULTS_CASE_INSENSITIVELY_MATCH_ROLE_NAME : false
2020-08-07 15:30:00.063945+0530 Public Adjuster[8759:2454775] Warning: Encountered `nil view` during signing
```

Sometime it gives this error

```
DSM_SETUP_RECIPIENT_DEFAULTS_CASE_INSENSITIVELY_MATCH_ROLE_NAME allows to override strict matching for roleNames.
```

Also i want to know that do we get envelope ID after the PDF is signed and sent, as i didnt see any method where it return the envelope ID in iOS SDK.

Any help will be appreciated, already talked with docusign support team and they asked to post our queries here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340118/docusign-ios-sdk-directly-sending-envelope-without-opening-anything-also-not-ask

Answer (score 0):

The following call can be made for an existing template on the account with nil `tabData` & `recipientData`. Are you getting an `error` back in the completion block?

```
func displayTemplateForSignature(templateId: String, controller: UIViewController, tabData: Dictionary<String, String>, recipientData: Array<DSMRecipientDefault>, customFields:DSMCustomFields?, onlineSign: Bool, attachmentUrl: URL?, completionHandler: @escaping ((UIViewController?, Error?) -> Void))
```

Are there any signers already added to the template with name/email/rolename? If yes, then it's likely that SDK is creating an envelope with the given template and sending it directly. To confirm direct send, add the notification listeners and check if on DocuSign web, you see a newly `sent` envelopes.

Depending on the signing mode (online vs offline) used, SDK would send the DSMSigningCompletedNotification or DSMEnvelopeCachedNotification notifications. In case of any error, for example, if unsupported tab types added to template, SDK sends DSMSigningCancelledNotification for online signing. Please note that all of these notifications have userInfo object that contains the `envelopeId` or `templateId`, please add this detail if you are getting such failures, open an issue at [GitHub page](https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk/issues).

a) Notifications can be used to get the `envelopeId` back for a signed envelope. [NotificationCodes Header](https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk/blob/master/DocuSignSDK.framework/Headers/DSMNotificationCodes.h)

b) The following error can be fixed by editing the `recipientDefaults` to match the template setup. If you decided to do that, do refer to helpful info at [open issue.](https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk/issues/43)

```
2020-08-07 15:30:00.063586+0530 Public Adjuster[8759:2454775] Error encountered during signing: Template has invalid recipient(s) associated with roleName: signer. Current Setup config for DSM_SETUP_RECIPIENT_DEFAULTS_CASE_INSENSITIVELY_MATCH_ROLE_NAME : false
```

Comment: Yes we are creating a template using our own backend call, and using the newly created template id i am opening the signing controller of SDK, but the issue is that no information of sender or recipient is added while uploading the template.
so if we passing nil data in recipientData then SDK shows no error and nothing opens.
and if i add name and email in recipient data then ,"Error encountered during signing: Template has invalid recipient(s) associated with roleName:" this error comes.

Comment: Now i have manually added roleName, recipientName, recipientEmail and used same data in app for recipientData.
now when i am calling displayTemplateForSignature

No screen is opening, i am directly getting.
name = DSMSigningCompletedNotification, object = Optional(<Public_Adjuster.AgreementSignViewController: 0x111e45180>), userInfo = Optional([AnyHashable("envelopeId"): 7b4f0edb-e1d0-4154-aa5a-4497d294d085, AnyHashable("templateId"): 506346f5-7adb-4132-b15f-d288aa268398, AnyHashable("signingMode"): online])

The envelope is directly sent without asking for signature

Comment: Thank you Ashokds for the help to get envelopeID..i am able to extract envelope id now..
please help in opening the signature screen for pdf..now its sending the document without asking for signature..

Comment: followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340118/docusign-ios-sdk-directly-sending-envelope-without-opening-anything-also-not-ask