# Docusign iOS SDK directly sending envelope without opening anything also not asking to do the signature

Tags: ios, swift, docusignapi

I have created a template in docusign web and using its template id, i am calling the function from iOS SDK.

```
TemplatesManager.sharedInstance.displayTemplateForSignature(templateId: templateId, controller: self, tabData: tabData, recipientData: recipientData, customFields:customFields, onlineSign: onlineSign, attachmentUrl: attachmentUrl) { (controller, errMsg) in
    print(errMsg)
}
```

The recipient data i am sending is

```
let recipientDatum = DSMRecipientDefault()
// Use recipient roleName (other option to use recipient-id) to find unique recipient in the template
recipientDatum.recipientRoleName = "Client"
recipientDatum.recipientSelectorType = .recipientRoleName
recipientDatum.recipientType = .inPersonSigner
// In-person-signer name
recipientDatum.inPersonSignerName = "Akshay Somkuwar"
// Host name (must match the name on the account) and email
recipientDatum.recipientName = "Akshay Somkuwar"
recipientDatum.recipientEmail = "akshay.s.somkuwar@gmail.com"
let recipientData: Array = [recipientDatum]
```

Same recipient is added for template in docusign website

[image]

Also i have added observers for `DSMSigningCompleted` and `DSMSigningCancelled` to get `envelopeId`.

Now when i am calling this function `displayTemplateForSignature` no screen is opening to show the PDF or To sign the PDF, without asking for signature, the envelope is directly sent to the recipient. and i am getting this response in console with notification.

```
name = DSMSigningCompletedNotification, object = Optional(<Public_Adjuster.AgreementSignViewController: 0x110bb8060>), userInfo = Optional([AnyHashable("templateId"): 506346f5-7adb-4132-b15f-d288aa268398, AnyHashable("signingMode"): online, AnyHashable("envelopeId"): 2eeeeda8-5b74-4930-904e-94b2ce6451ac])
```

I want to open the pdf for the passed `templateId` but its not opening the pdf nor its asking for `signature`, and its directly sent to the recipient.

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Previous Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312170/docusign-ios-sdk-integration-issue-in-custom-flowin-integrating-own-backend-and/63335134#63335134

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour, sending the envelope directly, is triggered when DocuSign SDK can not find any signers in the template/envelope that matches the logged-in user. Given that you are using the `recipientDefaults`, ensure that your signer information on the template (preset signer on the DocuSign web) matches the Account information exactly with the `recipientDefaults` object.

You may compare it with [image: Accout info accessible via preferences on DocuSign web].

One issue I noticed is the signer type is set to `need to sign` which corresponds to a `remoteSigner` on the DocuSign web. And on the `recipientDefaults` object it's set as `inPersonSigner`. It should be `.signer` corresponding to `DSMRecipientTypeSigner`.

`recipientDatum.recipientType = .signer`.

Or you may change the `need to sign` to `in person signer` on the DocuSign web.

[image]

Another suggestion is to remove the `name` & `email` from the template screenshot shared and keep that empty as the client app is passing `name` & `email` with the `recipientDefaults` object to the SDK.

More details: [How to set recipient defaults](https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk/issues/43#issuecomment-670092132)

Comment: Previous Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312170/docusign-ios-sdk-integration-issue-in-custom-flowin-integrating-own-backend-and/63335134#63335134